# Change how structured arrays and recarrays are printed

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, recarray, structured-array

Numpy summarizes large `arrays`, which is convenient when working in an interactive session.  Unfortunately, structured `arrays` and `recarrays` are not summarized very well by default.  Is there a way to change this?

By default, the full `array` is displayed if there are 1000 or fewer items.  When there are more items than this the `array` is summarized.  This can be set with `np.set_printoptions(threshold=<number of items to trigger summarization>, edgeitems=<number of items to show in summary>)`.
This works fine for standard datatypes, for example:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=3, edgeitems=1)
print(np.zeros(3))
print(np.zeros(4))
```

results in

```
[ 0.  0.  0.]
[ 0. ...,  0.]
```

However, when more complex datatypes are used, the summarization is less helpful

```
print(np.zeros(4, dtype=[('test', 'i4', 3)]))
print(np.zeros(4, dtype=[('test', 'i4', 4)]))

[([0, 0, 0],) ..., ([0, 0, 0],)]
[([0, 0, 0, 0],) ..., ([0, 0, 0, 0],)]
```

The array is summarized, but the sub datatypes are not.  This becomes a problem with large `arrays` using complex datatypes.  For instance the `array` `np.zeros(1000, dtype=[('a', float, 3000), ('b', float, 10000)])` hangs up my ipython instance.

There are a couple of workarounds, rather than using the `np.array` type directly it's possible to subclass and write a custom `__repr__`.  This would work for big projects, but doesn't solve the underlying issue and isn't convenient for quick exploration of data in an interactive python session.
I've also implemented a custom filter in my editor that truncates very long console output.  This is a bit of a hack and doesn't help when I fire up a python session elsewhere.

Is there a numpy setting I'm unaware of, or a python or ipython setting that could fix this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such controls or customization.  GIven the possible diversity it would take a lot of work to develop a general purpose formatter.  But if there's anything, I'd expect to find it in `np.core.records` which implements the `recarray` subclass.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks.  That makes sense and indeed I don't see anything in `np.core.records` that looks like it would affect that.

Comment: @hpaulj, I've posted an answer with a fairly general formatter.  I've been using it for awhile without error now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I've come up with that allows for sensible printing of record arrays.

```
def count_dtype(dtype):
    """
    dtype : datatype descr (list of strings / tuples, subdtypes rather than dtype object)
    Return total number of elements in array of dtype
    """
    sum = 0
    for name, t, *shape in dtype:
        if isinstance(t, str): ## base datatype
            if shape:
                sum += np.multiply.reduce(shape[0], dtype=np.int64)
            else:
                sum += 1
        else: ## Subarray type
            sum += np.multiply.reduce(shape, dtype=np.int64)*count_dtype(t)
    return sum


def _recarray2string(a, options, separator=' ', prefix=""):
    """
    Create a string representation of a record array
    a : record array
    separator : used by _array2string
    prefix : used by _array2string
    """
    options = np.get_printoptions()
    threshold = options['threshold']
    edgeitems = options['edgeitems']

    size = count_dtype(a.dtype.descr)
    items = np.multiply.reduce(a.shape)
    if size*items > threshold/(2*edgeitems): ## Too big
        if size > threshold: ## subtype is too large - how to handle?
            newopt = options.copy()
            newopt['threshold'] = options['threshold'] // (2*options['edgeitems'])
            def fmt_subtype(r):
                res = []
                for sub in r:
                    if sub.dtype.names is not None:
                        res.append(fmt_subtype(sub))
                    else:
                        res.append(_array2string(sub, newopt, separator=separator, prefix=prefix))
                return separator.join(res)
            return separator.join(fmt_subtype(a[i]) for i in range(edgeitems)) + '\n...\n' + \
                   separator.join(fmt_subtype(a[a.shape[0]-i-1]) for i in range(edgeitems))
        else: ## Subtype is small enough it's sufficient to truncate only sub-dtype
            options = options.copy()
            options['threshold'] = threshold // size
            return _array2string_old(a, options, separator=separator, prefix=prefix)
    else:  ## Print as normal
        return _array2string_old(a, options, separator=separator, prefix=prefix)


def _array2string(a, options , separator=' ', prefix=""):
    """
    monkeypatched print function that allows truncating record arrays sensibly
    """
    if a.dtype.names is not None:
        return  _recarray2string(a, options, separator=separator, prefix=prefix)
    else:
        return _array2string_old(a, options, separator=separator, prefix=prefix)


# Setup monkeypatching
_array2string_old = np.core.arrayprint._array2string
np.core.arrayprint._array2string = _array2string
```